# Convert string into array of int

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, parseint

I want to convert `"1,2,3"` to `[1,2,3]`.
But there is an exception when converting `""` to array. Because I get `[""]`. That is not valid for my case. So I need to check is it number or String. Let see this in code

```
function someWayToParse(some_string) {
    var final_product = [];

    var tmp_array = some_string.split(',');

    //if some_string == "" tmp_array will result [""];
    if (tmp_array[0].length===0)
        return [];

    for (var item in tmp_array)
        final_product.push(parseInt(tmp_array[item], 10));

    return final_product;
}

var stringToParse = "1,2,3";

var array_of_ints = someWayToParse(stringToParse);
```

I am just looking the best way to do this in a function and avoid possible mistakes.
Please be memory efficient, for my curiosity's sake.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is best suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: 1) check for empty string first, 2) stop iterating over arrays with `for..in`.

Comment: @raina77ow I agree with 1) but i would like for some elaboration of 2). Don't get me wrong I don't say you are wrong just want to learn why.

Comment: @Satpal can I move question there, do I need separate registration on that stack. Sorry for small questions, I am new to Stack community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Smaller code for it would be:

```
function myConverter(string) {
  if (!string) return [];
  return string.split(',').map(Number);
}

console.log(myConverter('1,2,3'));
```

Comment: As raina77ow said I could check for empty string in start and use rest of you logic. First time seeing this map() thing. I'll google it a bit before use, but looks legit.

Comment: @MihajloSupic after reading your code for the second time i realized that you mentioned what you wanted to return for the empty string, so i added it in my implementation.

Comment: For all unfamiliar with map like I was this morning, enjoy:
[link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
Thank you @Tibos.

Comment: I also use jquery in this project but I didn't mentioned it so I trim everything that comes in to the function to be sure it will stay string. Then if string is empty return []. Otherwise i use your map split mighty code.